# How to call ajax functions in sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want ajax functions to execute one after another without `asynch: false`. Because `asynch : false` puts browser in a hang mode. 
My code is like this
I have 5 checkboxes
**ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5**
 each with a value as function name. User can select any number of check boxes but the ajax function associated with checkbox values should execute one after another only.
Lets user selects
 **ch1, ch5, ch3**
so functions should execute like

```
f1() -> f3() - >f5();
```

functions are like this

```
function f1(){
    $.ajax({

    });
} 
function f2(){
    $.ajax({

    });
} 
function f3(){
    $.ajax({

    });
}
.
.
so on
```

I tried calling successive function in ajax success method but this creates a problem if user selects random checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation like this.
**Solution**
First make an array of selected checkboxes with values as array elements. Then make a function that check for that value and call its corresponding function.

```
 function callRequired(array) {
            var required = array[0];
            if (required === "f1") {
                f1(array);
            }
            if (required === "f2") {
                f2(array);
            }
            if (required === "f3") {
                f3(array);
            }
            if (required === "f4") {
                f4(array);
            }
            if (required === "f5") {
                f5(array);
            }
        }
```

We are here checking the first element as required callback. Then removing it after each success. Simply remove that element and call `callRequired(array)` by removing the previous element as follows

```
function f1(array) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "some/url",
            success: function (response) {
                array.splice(0, 1);
                callRequired(array);
            }
        });
    }
function f2(array) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "some/url",
            success: function (response) {
                array.splice(0, 1);
                callRequired(array);
            }
        });
    }
function f3(array) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "some/url",
            success: function (response) {
                array.splice(0, 1);
                callRequired(array);
            }
        });
    }
function f4(array) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "some/url",
            success: function (response) {
                array.splice(0, 1);
                callRequired(array);
            }
        });
    }
function f5(array) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "some/url",
            success: function (response) {
                array.splice(0, 1);
                callRequired(array);
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use `jQuery.when`:

```
var ajax1 = $.ajax(...);
var ajax2 = $.ajax(...);

//You can pass as much arguments as needed here
$.when(ajax1, ajax2).done(function(){
    alert('All requests complete');
});
```

See the docs for reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: it may be f2() after f1() or f3() after f1(), the sequence can be of any order. We dont exactly know what is the sequence.

Comment: @Krishna The ajax call is made in the order you create the jqXHR objects with `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0):

can you make one common function which call on checkbox change event with one common class than after you can also define some unique id in data-attributes of checkbox and fetch that using jquery attributes method according to that value you can call ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Call one function inside each other, like:

```
function f1(){
    $.ajax({
        success: function(){
            f2();
        }
    });
} 
function f2(){
    $.ajax({
        success: function(){
            f3();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: *"but this creates a problem if user selects random checkboxes."*

Comment: No one knows f2() will be called inside f1(). It is independent

Comment: This option preserves async, and in each `success` you can do any logic needed. Also you can do it with `jquery.when`, as said @CarlosCarucce

Answer (score 0):

Given i have no example code, i would do it this way.

- Associate each element to a function to be called. Like, an object with keys corresponding to checkboxes ids, and values corresponding to callbacks:
- Select via jQuery all the checkboxes, preserving order
- Filter out unchecked ones
- Map the obtained list of checkboxes to an array, whose elements are the values (= callback functions)

You should have now something like:

```
var callbacks = [callback_one, callback_three, callback_four];
```

where ideally "one", "three", "four" are corresponding callbacks to selected checkboxes. You then keep an integer value pointing to current callback getting called.

Finally, you launch the first callback. Upon `success`, you increase the integer value, and if it's less than the length of the callback list, you call the next callback.